# Entity Framework EDMX in C# hiding parameter values with @p__linq__0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, iqueryable, edmx

I inherited some projects in which apparently the VS application is using old EDMX.  I don't recall having such a hard time with queries in the past, especially with figuring out parameters ..

As I step through the code I see various `IQueryable<T>` statements such as

```
IQueryable<BreakDomainModel> breakDomainModels = breakFactoryService.ReadBreakData();
```

Everyone seems to be so hidden that troubleshooting it becomes difficult.

**Example of part of the SQL**

```
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BreakId] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent3].[Name] ELSE @p__linq__0 END AS [C6], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BreakId] IS NOT NULL) THEN  CAST( [Extent2].[DateCreated] AS datetime2) END AS [C7], 
[Extent1].[ExceptionType] AS [ExceptionType], 
[Extent1].[LinkId] AS [LinkId], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BreakId] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent2].[Age] ELSE @p__linq__1 END AS [C8]
```

How can I step through the code and actually get the values of `@p__linq__0`  etc.. ?

I can provide more code if needed,  but simply F11 and using watches is just not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your own [DbCommandInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbcommandinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx). Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) article on EF logging. Note that in order to log the parameters you'll have to iterate over `DbCommand.Parameters`. A minimal solution to log the Select queries would be:

```
public class LoggingCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command,
        DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        var parameters = command.Parameters.Cast<DbParameter>()
            .Select(x => $"{x.ParameterName}:{x.Value}");
        // It's up to you how you initialize the logger
        GetLogger().Debug($"Parameters: {string.Join(", ", parameters)}\r\n Query: {command.CommandText}");

        base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
    }
}
```

And then all you need to do is register that interceptor in your application startup code (global.asax/Startup.cs/etc):

```
DbInterception.Add(new LoggingCommandInterceptor());
```

If you care only about getting to the parameters when debugging just put a breakpoint inside the method, it'll hit every time EF accessed the database.

Please note that you'll have to override the other methods (`NonQueryExecuting()` and `ScalarExecuting()`) the same way in order to intercept the update/instert/delete queries as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a sample

Comment: Updated my answer to include a minimal proof of concept

Answer (score -1):

It will probably be easiest to run a SQL profiler session to see the generated query.

See this answer for the better solution:
[View Generated Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Comment: Certainly seems like it, this is a nightmare.  I forget how to use sql profiler - I wonder if I even have the permissions !    ugh

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you as its a valid way of doing it.   I don't have the db permissions to even do the profiler - I just tried

Comment: I just added a link to another stackoverflow article with a solution.